# Solve::ivar: (a11+I a12)^2 is not a valid variable

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have tried

```
M = {{(a11 + I a12)^2, (b11 + I b12)^2, (c11 + I c12)^2}, {(b11 + 
  I b12)^2, (d11 + I d12)^2, (e11 + I e12)^2}, {(c11 + 
  I c12)^2, (e11 + I e12)^2, (f11 + I f12)^2}};
A = {{-1, 9, 0}, {8, 5, 9}, {0, 2, 4}}
G = Transpose[A].M.A
Solve[G == Conjugate[M], Flatten[M]]
```

The last line creating problem that Solve::ivar: (a11+I a12)^2 is not a valid variable. Can we simplify such matrix equality and simply get the simplified M matrix without doing it by hand

Comment: A solution for this system as it is, is given by **a11=a12=b11=b12=c11=c12=d11=d12=e11=e12=f11=f12=0**

Comment: Thanks @Cesareo but how using mathematica I can solve for those conditions and by not solving individually all the equations

Answer (score 2):

Solve a simpler problem...

```
mm2 = {{m11, m12, m13},
       {m12, m22, m23},
       {m13, m23, m33}};

gg2 = Transpose[aa].mm2.aa;

Solve[gg2 == Conjugate[mm2], Union@Flatten@mm2];


(* {{m11 -> 0, m12 -> 0, m13 -> 0, m22 -> 0, m23 -> 0, m33 -> 0}} *)
```

So as @Cesareo notes in the comments, all of the parameters are zero.

Comment: So according to your code is it can be done for the above system also since mine problem is not taking (a11+i a12) as a variable

Comment: Correct, since we now know (a11+i a12)^2 = 0, we know each of a11 and a12 = 0.

Comment: ok thanks. Actually my original matrix is more complex but I think I must try your method to my original matrix also